# How to tee stdout/stderr from a subprocess in Rust

Tags: rust, subprocess

I'd like to capture stdout/stderr of a subprocess but also stream the outputs to my process' stdout/stderr as well. In bash I'd do something like:

```
my_command > >(tee /tmp/capture.out) 2> >(tee /tmp/capture.err >&2)
```

Is there any reasonably concise or typical way to do this in Rust? Looking at [`std::process::Child.wait_with_output()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d9a105f/library/std/src/process.rs#L1644) and [`sys::pipe::read2`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d9a105f/library/std/src/sys/unix/pipe.rs#L76) handling stdout/stderr directly seems somewhat involved (and involves an `unsafe` call to `poll`).

Another way of framing the question might be "what's the expected way to stream over a subprocess' stdout and stderr?" which would at least allow me to manually capture and print the streams' contents.

I'm currently using `std::process` but if it's easier with the `subprocess` crate I'd be willing to swap to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along those lines?

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{stderr, stdout, Read, Write},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
    thread,
};

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("/usr/bin/date")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to execute child");

    fn communicate(
        mut stream: impl Read,
        filename: &'static str,
        mut output: impl Write,
    ) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut file = File::create(filename)?;

        let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
        loop {
            let num_read = stream.read(&mut buf)?;
            if num_read == 0 {
                break;
            }

            let buf = &buf[..num_read];
            file.write_all(buf)?;
            output.write_all(buf)?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    let child_out = std::mem::take(&mut child.stdout).expect("cannot attach to child stdout");
    let child_err = std::mem::take(&mut child.stderr).expect("cannot attach to child stderr");

    let thread_out = thread::spawn(move || {
        communicate(child_out, "stdout.txt", stdout())
            .expect("error communicating with child stdout")
    });
    let thread_err = thread::spawn(move || {
        communicate(child_err, "stderr.txt", stderr())
            .expect("error communicating with child stderr")
    });

    thread_out.join().unwrap();
    thread_err.join().unwrap();

    let ecode = child.wait().expect("failed to wait on child");

    assert!(ecode.success());
}
```

Output:

```
Tue Jul  5 01:07:01 CEST 2022
```

`stdout.txt`:

```
Tue Jul  5 01:07:01 CEST 2022
```

Comment: This is neat and works also for commands which continuously stream to stdout and stderr!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It's taken me a while to get around to implementing it, but I finally have [done so](https://github.com/dimo414/bkt/pull/43) and I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3):

> handling stdout/stderr directly seems somewhat involved (and involves an unsafe call to poll

It's probably going to be involved either way as Rust doesn't really have abstractions over complicated pipe & fd operations and this requires a fair number of them: creating two pipes and doing a lot of dup'ing around to properly set all the input and output streams to match.

The "easy" way to do this (it's not actually easy but it avoids having to deal with libc and fds) would be to spawn threads to explicitly copy data around between the various bits.